# Lint error : Package not included in Android: java.awt. Referenced from com.sun.jna.Native.AWT

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, lint

I am getting the following error :

````
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':libraries:shared:lintDevDebug'.
>                 Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.
  
                  Fix the issues identified by lint, or create a baseline to see only new errors:
                  ```
                  android {
                      lint {
                          baseline = file("lint-baseline.xml")
                      }
                  }
                  ```
  
                  For more details, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#snapshot
  
                  Lint found 9 errors, 0 warnings (19 errors filtered by baseline lint-baseline.xml). First failure:
  
  C:\Users\cloudtest\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\jna\5.6.0\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\jna-5.6.0.jar: Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: java.awt. Referenced from com.sun.jna.Native.AWT. [InvalidPackage]
````

Not sure how to deal with it. I don't understand fully what is causing this issue so could not take a step to fix it. Will share more details if required. Thanks.